# How can I except a line with grep?

Tags: grep

sorry for my beginner question: I want to grep links in a .md-file except a special line, which beginns with a special word.

So my index.md looks like:

```
[Test](202001-test)
BlaBla: [Test2]((202002-test2)
```

My code looks like:

```
grep -Eo '\[.*\]\([2].*\)' ~/script/index.md
```

So what should I write, that grep ignore the second line? Found no answer on the regular expression websites.

Greetings

Comment: Append `| grep -v '^BlaBla'`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, nice that you have shared your code, could you please post sample of your expected output too in your question and let us know then.

Comment: It only matches `[Test](202001-test)` because on the second line, there must be a digit straight after a `](` (but there is `((`). Or is there a typo in the input string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: damn. yes there is a typo in the line... sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the point is to match substrings like `[...](2...)` that do not contain extra `[` and `]` inside the square brackets and `(` / `)` in between parentheses, and if you want **to avoid matching strings starting with `BlaBla:`**, you may consider using

```
grep -v '^BlaBla:' index.md | grep -o '\[[^][]*](2[^()]*)'
```

Here, `grep -v '^BlaBla:'` inverts the match with `-v` option and outputs all lines that do NOT start with `BlaBla:`. Then, the second `grep` gets the necessary valid matches.

**POSIX BRE pattern details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(2` - a `(2` substring
- `[^()]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `)` - a `)` char.

See [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/bCEyBN):

```
s='[Test](202001-test)
BlaBla: [Test2]((202002-test2)'
grep -v '^BlaBla:' <<< "$s" | grep -o '\[[^][]*](2[^()]*)'
```

Output:

```
[Test](202001-test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! In my first post there was a typo. So the correct text is without double (. So your output is correct. But I need line 2 to be ignored from the script.

Comment: So I edited my code with grep -v 'BlaBla:...' index.md | your code. And it seems to work. Is this a good solution?